# Liquid: How to exclude certain properties from object

Tags: liquid

I have a liquid object that contains multiple attributes such as id, description, price etc.

I would like to be able to filter this object so that specific properties are excluded from the object. Alternatively, if that is not possible, I would like to be able to copy the object and modify the copy to change the values of select attributes - specifically setting the description to be blank.